# How to use a for loop to add to a previous value until the loop is over?

Tags: javascript

Focusing on the for loop. I want the interest to build off the latest value variable. When this script is ran I get the same interest rate for every year and the same value. I want it to use the last value variable to calculate what the new value is for each year. Here is how the program shows up in a browser:
Year: 1
Interest: 750
Value: 10750

Year: 2
Interest: 750
Value: 10750

Year: 3
Interest: 750
Value: 10750

Year: 4
Interest: 750
Value: 10750

Year: 5
Interest: 750
Value: 10750

Investment amount = 10000 Interest rate = 7.5 Years = 5 Future Value is 10750

Thanks for using the Future Value application.The value and the interest should increment.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">  
        <title>Future Value Application</title>
<script>
    var futureValue;


    var investment = prompt("Enter investment amount as xxxxx.xx", 10000);
    investment = parseFloat(investment);
    var rate = prompt("Enter interest rate as xx.x", 7.5);
    rate = parseFloat(rate);
    var years = prompt("Enter number of years", 10);
    years = parseInt(years);



    // calulate future value
    futureValue = investment;


    for (var i = 1; i <= years; i++ ) {
        var cInterest;
        var value;
        document.write("Year: " +(i) + "<br>");
        cInterest = futureValue * rate / 100;
        cInterest = parseInt(cInterest);
        document.write("Interest: " + cInterest + "<br>");
        value = futureValue + cInterest;
        value = parseInt(value);
        document.write ("Value: " + value + "<br><br>");
        cInterest += value;
    }
    futureValue = parseInt(futureValue);


 </script>
   </head>
   <body>
<main>
    <script>
        document.write("Investment amount = " + investment);
        document.write(" Interest rate = " + rate);
        document.write(" Years = " + years);
        document.write(" Future Value is " + (futureValue + futureValue* rate / 100) + "<br><br>");
    </script>
    Thanks for using the Future Value application.
</main>
```

Comment: Not clear what you have problem with - definitely you know how to change values of variables - so why don't you do in your loop? Side note: Consider reading something about JavaScript... declaring variables inside loop does not give you any scoping benefit...

Comment: You have to give us precise information about the financial algorythm you want to apply here :-)
The interest rate is added to the investement every year: (investment+interest last year)*interest rate...?

Comment: Year: 1
Interest: 750
Value: 10750

Year: 2
Interest: 750
Value: 10750

Year: 3
Interest: 750
Value: 10750

Year: 4
Interest: 750
Value: 10750

Year: 5
Interest: 750
Value: 10750

Investment amount = 10000 Interest rate = 7.5 Years = 5 Future Value is 10750

Thanks for using the Future Value application. This is how my program looks like and as you can see I want the interest to accumuluate every year then give me the final return on investment.

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking a look at this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx

As alexei mentioned in his comment, both your value and cInterest variables are declared inside your for loop. The values of these variables only last through the scope which they are present in. In this case, both of these variables are inside the for loop. So, after each iteration, they are being re-initialized.

I am not sure of what you specifically want to happen, but you could do:

```
    var cInterest;
    var value; //not sure what you want to do with this.
    for (var i = 1; i <= years; i++ ) {

    document.write("Year: " +(i) + "<br>");
    cInterest = futureValue * rate / 100;
    cInterest = parseInt(cInterest);
    document.write("Interest: " + cInterest + "<br>");
    value = futureValue + cInterest; //value is getting 'reset' here.
    value = parseInt(value);
    document.write ("Value: " + value + "<br><br>");
    cInterest += value;
}
futureValue = parseInt(futureValue);
```

Your cInterest should be properly calculated with this. However, I am unsure of what you planned to do with the value variable.